# adb.exe does not exist react native

Tags: react-native, adb

while runing react native giving error

> File 'C:\Users\inbox\AppData\Local\Android\platform-tools\adb.exe'
>   specified for property 'adbExe' does not exist.  while adb.exe exist
>   in path  C:\Users\inbox\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

what is the solution for above problem?

Answer (score 1):

I hit this same issue...

Notice that these two paths actually are not the same:
C:\Users\inbox\AppData\Local\Android\platform-tools\adb.exe
C:\Users\inbox\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe

To fix this, I just created a new folder "platform-tools" at 'C:\Users\inbox\AppData\Local\Android\' and then moved the files adb.exe, AdbWinApi.dll, Adb.WinUsbApi.dll into that folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my case, I had /platform-tools/platform-tools/adb, so I just moved the adb up a folder like you suggested and the problem was solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be you forgot to add path of `adb` in `SystemsVariable` so add adb path 
Here is the guide for [How to Add Adb path](https://www.xda-developers.com/adb-fastboot-any-directory-windows-linux/)