# React Native: Task :app:installDebug FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle, daemon

I am working on **MAC**, trying to run React Native on **android** but it throws this error: `Task :app:installDebug FAILED`. This is the full error:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
27 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 25 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:installDebug'.
> File '/Users/vinaysharma/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb' specified for property 'adbExe' does not exist.

Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8088

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:installDebug'.
> File '/Users/vinaysharma/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb' specified for property 'adbExe' does not exist.
```

I've tried reinstalling Android Studio twice as well as creating a new project for RN but that didn't help me out.

I **tried** this as well: `brew cask install android-platform-tools`. Thanks.

Comment: did you run command adb devices after that

Comment: @RishiSahu yes, I did. It shows list of devices.

Comment: then adb is working and installed is it showing your devices id or any number?

Comment: It maybe a path related issue please follow this thread ['adbExe' does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51928659/9756445)

Comment: @RishiSahu yes, it's showing device id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install adbExe. Please follow steps in [this link](https://www.xda-developers.com/adb-fastboot-any-directory-windows-linux/)

Comment: Hi, I am working on mac, but this link is all about WIN and LINUX.